# Find the path taken by the user in a drop down menu

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, widget

I am using menu widgets in tkinter to create a drop down menu, I need to have some code, so that when one of the commands are clicked, the route taken by the user to get to that command is found. This is because the command needed will be dependent on which route the user has taken to get to that command. How can I find the path taken by the user? Here is my code

```
team1 = 'Lakers'
team2 = 'Celtics'

def makeShot():
    print ("Shot was made by")

# Setting up the window and the title etc.     
root = Tk()
root.title("Basketball Code")
root.geometry("850x700")

# Lists for the 2 teams.
team1Players = ("Zach Auguste", "Tarik Black", "Anthony Brown", "Jose Calderon", "Luol Deng")
team2Players = ("Ben Bentil", "Avery Bradley", "Jaylen Brown", "Jae Crowder", "Gerald Green")

# Create a popup menu for selecting a team. 
teamMenu = Menu(root)

Team2Menu = Menu(root)
Team1Menu = Menu(root)

# Create the 2 options for picking the teams.
teamMenu.add_cascade(label=team1, menu = Team1Menu)
teamMenu.add_cascade(label=team2, menu = Team2Menu)

# Adding the player names to the drop down list
team1Menu = Menu(root)
for i in range(len(team1Players)):
    Team1Menu.add_cascade(label=team1Players[i], menu=team1Menu)

# Adding the player names to the drop down list
team2Menu = Menu(root)
for i in range(len(team2Players)):
    Team2Menu.add_cascade(label=team2Players[i], menu=team2Menu)

#Adding the options to the players name list.
shotTypeMenu = Menu(root)
team1Menu.add_cascade(label= "3pt", menu=shotTypeMenu)
team1Menu.add_cascade(label= "2pt", menu=shotTypeMenu)
team2Menu.add_cascade(label= "3pt", menu=shotTypeMenu)
team2Menu.add_cascade(label= "2pt", menu=shotTypeMenu)


#Adding the options to the players name list.
shotSuccessMenu = Menu(root)
shotTypeMenu.add_command(label= "Make", command = makeShot)
shotTypeMenu.add_command(label= "Miss", command = None)

def popup(event):
    teamMenu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    print(event.x,",",event.y)

#Attach popup to frame
root.bind("<Button-3>", popup)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You only need a list to store the previous choices and decide where to append items to the list in your code and when to clear the list.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your comment please, I don't understand.

Comment: No I can't because your question is unclear. You want to fetch the previous choices, it means that when a choice is made you must store it in a list. Now this list must be cleared now and then. Only you know when it must be done

Comment: But they are not technically 'choices', as you can see, they are cascades, so you don't need to click them, only hover your mouse over them.

Comment: You could perhaps add callbacks for the postcommand and tearoffcommand menu widget's options.

Comment: could you give me an example? I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: I think it would be easier to create one `shotTypeMenu` per player, with the wanted callback instead of making one global `shotTypeMenu` and trying to figure out which team/player was selected.